# Connect to GSuite Admin Service through Apps Script with OAuth token - scope https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, access-token, google-workspace

I try to complete the following values in order to execute an application to put signatures to all users of a G Suite domain:

[image]

[image]

Some weeks ago, it was ok, but now I can't save the correct values to finish the configuration. I hope someone knows what is happening.

UPDATE 1:

AdminOauth2.gs

```
function getAdminService() {

return OAuth2.createService('AdminEmail')
  .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
  .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
  .setClientId(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
               .getProperty("clientId"))
  .setClientSecret(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
               .getProperty("clientSecret"))
  .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
  .setScope('https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/')
  .setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())
  .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
  .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');
 }

function showAuthWindow() {
  var adminService = getAdminService();
  if (!adminService.hasAccess()) {
     var authorizationUrl = adminService.getAuthorizationUrl();
     var template = HtmlService.createTemplate(
    '<a href="<?= authorizationUrl ?>" target="_blank">Authorize</a> ');
    template.authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl;
    var page = template.evaluate();
    return page;
 } else {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("You have already authorized this service");
 }
}

function authCallback(request) {
 var adminService = getAdminService();
 var isAuthorized = adminService.handleCallback(request);
 if (isAuthorized) {
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this tab.');
 } else {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
 }
}

function clearService(){
  OAuth2.createService('AdminEmail')
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
  .reset();
}
```

codigo.gs

```
/*AdminOauth2*/
function doGet(){
 return showAuthWindow();
}

function authScript(){
  return true;
}

var KEY = "midominio.com"; // Dominio

var USERSHEETNAME  = "Usuarios"
var ADMINSHEETNAME = "Administración";

var USUARIOCOL   = "Nombre de usuario";
var ESDITIMECOL  = "Marca temporal";

function updateAllSignatures(){
   Logger.log('[updateAllSignatures]');
   var allDatas = getAllDatas();
   var recover = allDatas.admin.sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 1).getValues();
   var i;
   if (recover[0][0] == ""){
      i = 0;
   }else {
      i = recover;
   }

  var status;
  for (i ; i < allDatas.user.values.length ; i++){
    //Logger.log(allDatas.user.values.length);
  if (i > 0){
    var col = allDatas.user.titles[USUARIOCOL];
    var userValues = allDatas.user.values;
    var user = userValues[i][col];
  
  //generate signature for each users
   var signature = generateSignature(allDatas, user);
   status = updateSignature(user, signature);
   if (status != 200){
     return;
   }
  
  allDatas.admin.sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 1).setValues([[i]]);
  }
 }
 allDatas.admin.sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 1).setValues([[""]]);
 if (status == "200"){
   Logger.log("El script se ejecutó en su totalidad");
  }
  return;
}


function generateSignature(allDatas, userName){
  var signTplt = "";
  var user = userName.split("@")[0];
  var domain = userName.split("@")[1];


  var column=0;
  var i;
  for (i in allDatas.admin.values[0]){
    if (allDatas.admin.values[0][i] == domain ){
    column = i;
    }
  }
 if (column>0){
   signTplt = allDatas.admin.values[1][column];

   var userLine = allDatas.user.line[userName];
   var userData = allDatas.user.values[userLine];
   var titleData = allDatas.user.values[0];

 // foreach columns in data
 for (j in userData){
  if (userData[j] != ""){
    for (k in allDatas.admin.values){
      if (allDatas.admin.values[k][0] == titleData[j]+"_"){
        if (signTplt.split("["+allDatas.admin.values[k][0]+"]")[1] != null){
          signTplt = signTplt.split("["+allDatas.admin.values[k][0]+"]")[0]+allDatas.admin.values[k][column]+signTplt.split("["+allDatas.admin.values[k][0]+"]")[1];
        }//else{
          //signTplt = signTplt.split("["+allDatas.admin.values[k][0]+"]")[0]+signTplt.split("["+allDatas.admin.values[k][0]+"]")[1];
        //}
      }
    }
    if (signTplt.split("["+titleData[j]+"]")[1] != null){
      signTplt = signTplt.split("["+titleData[j]+"]")[0]+userData[j]+signTplt.split("["+titleData[j]+"]")[1];
    }
  }else{
    switch (titleData[j]){
      case "Cel Phone":
      default:
        if (signTplt.split("["+titleData[j]+"]")[1] != null){
          signTplt = signTplt.split("["+titleData[j]+"]")[0]+signTplt.split("["+titleData[j]+"]")[1];
        }
        if (signTplt.split("["+titleData[j]+"_]")[1] != null){
          signTplt = signTplt.split("["+titleData[j]+"_]")[0]+signTplt.split("["+titleData[j]+"_]")[1];
        }
        
        break;
    }
    
  }
  var temp=0
  }
 }
 return signTplt;
}

/**
* updateSignature(usuario, signature) //update the signature of user
**/
function updateSignature(usuario, signature) {
  var userName = usuario.split("@")[0]
  var domain = usuario.split("@")[1]
  var scope = 'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/'
  var xmlRaw = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
'<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:apps="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006">'+
  '<apps:property name="signature" value="'+htmlEncode(signature)+'" />'+
    '</atom:entry>'
  var name = 'signature'
  
  var base="https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/";
  var url = base + domain + '/' + userName + '/signature';

  var options = {
                 "method":"PUT",
                 "headers": {"authorization": "Bearer " + getAdminService().getAccessToken()},
                 "payload":xmlRaw,
                 "contentType":"application/atom+xml"
                }
  
  var url = scope+domain+'/'+userName+'/signature'
  var urlFetch
  var results
  var status = ""
  
  try{
    results =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log(results)
   
    status = results.getResponseCode()
    
    Logger.log(status)
    
    if (status != "200") {
      Logger.log("imposible to apply signature for this domain : " + status)
      Logger.log("Un error occurio. Verificar que el usuario : " + usuario + " esta valido verifica la cuenta principal del usuario en el panel de administracion Google Apps o aplica la firma para todos una vez")
    }
  }catch (e){
    Logger.log("El usuario " + usuario + " no existe. Error detail:" + e)
    return 200;
   }
return status;
}

 /**
 * htmlEncode(str) //replace element to comply with html code
 **/
function htmlEncode(str){
 str = str.replace(/&/g,'&#38;');
 str = str.replace(/</g,'&#60;');
 str = str.replace(/\"/g,'&#34;');
 str = str.replace(/>/g,'&#62;');
 str = str.replace(/nbsp;/g,'#160;');
 return str;
}
```

Comment: I've had the same problem.  If you want to report in on the Issue Tracker, I'll also "star" it.  [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues)  If you report it, get the link, and post it back to here.

Comment: Thanks, I added: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74285919

Comment: There may be an alternative for you, depending upon which API you are trying to use.  Are you trying to use a Google API?

Comment: I'm trying to connect to Admin SDK. I only activate this API.

Comment: An SDK is used in something other than Apps Script, like a different server side language.  If you are using Apps Script, then you don't need to use an SDK, and shouldn't even try to.  You can use an Advanced Service or the REST API.  In either of those cases, you can set a scope explicitly in the Apps Script manifest file.  But you need to know the scope URL.  You can see a list of the Admin scopes at the following link: [OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#admindirectory_v1)

Comment: If you are trying to do something like use an OAuth library, but there is either an Advance Service or a REST API that you can use, then you don't need a seperate Oauth library.  You can set the scope in the manifest file, and get the OAuth token with `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`  But, I'm not sure what your exact situation is.  You used the Apps Script tag, so I assume that you are writing the code in Apps Script and not some other server language.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use an OAuth library. I only use Apps Sript, not other server language. Before, I use the Admin SDK without problems, but not something has changed. I don't use a manifest file, all my configurations are on GAS. On Issuetracker, I don't have any help.

Comment: Are you getting an OAuth token for whatever code you are running?  Can you post the critical lines of code that need the Admin API?

Comment: Dear Sandy Good, I added my code to the post. It's necessary for the function "updateSignature". I added that code to the script editor of the  Google Sheets. Also I tried to create an instance OAuth2 but I can't link it with the project of the script editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get an access token to make the PUT request: `getAdminService().getAccessToken()`

The Options:

```
var options = {
             "method":"PUT",
             "headers": {"authorization": "Bearer " + getAdminService().getAccessToken()},
             "payload":xmlRaw,
             "contentType":"application/atom+xml"
            }
```

The access token is being chained to `getAdminService()`

And it looks like the scope that you need is:

```
'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/'
```

You could try setting that scope directly in the manifest file:

### appsscript.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "Your time zone here",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/",
              "All",
              "Your", 
              "Other", 
              "Scopes"]
}
```

To get all your other scopes, in the File menu, choose Project Properties, and then choose the Scopes tab.  Copy out the scopes.  Then in the View menu, view the manifest file.  Modify the manifest file.

So, what that does, when you set the scopes in the manifest file, is that Apps Script manages the OAuth stuff internally.  You may not need a library.

Then you can just get the token with: `var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();`

So, you would end up with:

```
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

var options = {
             "method":"PUT",
             "headers": {"authorization": "Bearer " + token},
             "payload":xmlRaw,
             "contentType":"application/atom+xml"
            }
```

If you are using the HTML Service, and web app, and call back just to get the OAuth token, then you don't need any of that, and you don't even need to use the Google Cloud console.

Comment: Excellent! It was very helpful.Your're right. I only need to include the correct scope in the manifest file.